# How to change excel workbook links in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, automation, excel-2019

I would like to change excel workbook links in Python.I was wondering how to go about doing this. Usually, on spreadsheets you would go to data and then click on workbook links and change a link to a new source. How can you do this through Python?

I tried using the function Changelinks() and linksource() but it didn’t work in win32

Comment: Hyperlinks or External links?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: They would be external links